# How to customize a footer on a Child Theme

Tags: wordpress, customization, footer

I am using a child-theme in wordpress.  What code would I add to the child theme's PhP or CSS file to customize the footer so that it displays a dynamic copyright date next to the name of the website in hyperlink centered on each page.

Answer (score 0):

Probably parent theme you are using has some hook to display copyright information. Find that hook and update it in functions.php of your child theme.

Furthermore, it would be easy to provide solution if you have mentioned the name of parent theme you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `footer.php` of the parent theme to your child theme. Then you need to add something like this in your child `functions.php`

```
function pietergoosen_copyright_in_footer() {
     $all_posts = get_posts('post_status=publish&order=ASC');
    $first_post = $all_posts[0];
    $first_date = $first_post->post_date_gmt;

    _e('Copyright &copy; ');
    if ( substr($first_date,0,4) == date('Y') ) {
      echo date('Y');
    } else {
      echo substr($first_date,0,4) . "-" . date('Y');
    }
    echo ' <strong>' . get_bloginfo('name') . '</strong> ';

}
```

This function will use the first and last post date to display the date for the copyright date. Then, in your footer, add `<?php echo pietergoosen_copyright_in_footer(); ?>` where you need to display this information. The styling you will need to sort out yourself according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

Copy the footer.php into you child theme folder and replace the year using the code below

```
<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your favorite text editor in my case I use Sublime. Then open the whole project folder and search for the footer. There you will see the footer details and you can comment on them and add what you want to appear on the footer.